# Load different parts of a single page site as the user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a website that has 5 different 'pages' all on one page, so it is a single page scrolling navigation website. Instead of the users browsers loading the whole page when they load the site, is there a way in which you can load the different virtual 'pages' as the user scrolls down to them? From here I could animate the elements when they load.

Comment: Yes you can do this, do you have something for people to work with? If you expect answers then we need something to work with. It would be a good idea for you to display your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for an out of the box option, I would check out [LazyLoadXT](https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt).

I used it on a site where I wanted divs to load as I went along. I'm sure with a little working you can get it to work by calling `divs`.